# SlideUp block in the block that is already SlidedUp

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a #cart_block_top_no_products with 'No products' text at the top right - here is the link http://livedemo07682.prestatrend.com just hover over the cart please. When adding product to the cart and quickly hover the cart we will see that product was added and #cart_block_top_no_products with 'No products' text SlidedUp. But if adding a product and not quickly hover the cart #cart_block_top_no_products with 'No products' text does not SlidedUp. It's not good looking. And here is the code:

```
//create a container for listing the products and hide the 'no product in the cart' message (only if the cart was empty)
                if ($('#cart_block_top dl.products').length == 0)
                    $('#cart_block_top p#cart_block_top_no_products').fadeTo('fast', 0, function(){
                        $(this).slideUp('fast').fadeTo(0, 1);
                    }).before('<dl class="products"></dl>');
```

Anybody help please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybey $('#cart_block_top dl.products').length returns 0 due to synchronizing problems (for example, this check is exectuted before the product is added to the cart.)
A solutions is to move this check to the ajax-call success method callback (see the call to cart.php):

```
success: function(jsonData,textStatus,jqXHR) {
    // other code
    if (jsonData.products == null || jsonData.products.length == 0) {
          $('#cart_block_top p#cart_block_top_no_products').fadeTo('fast', 0,        function(){
                    $(this).slideUp('fast').fadeTo(0, 1);
                }).before('<dl class="products"></dl>');
     }

}
```